# Statistical analysis of nonlinear equation

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I have the following equation:
$C_i = \frac{EF_eS_i\delta_wW_j(\frac{t_i}{t_j})^m(\frac{v_i}{v_j})^n\alpha_w\gamma_f}{dwtD_i}$

where $S_i = S_{base}(.455L_i^2-.710L_i+1.280)$

And $L_i = \frac{v_i}{v_j}$

This is a simplified description of a ship's ($i$) carbon intensity for each hour at sea during a voyage. I have data to compute the equation and know what exponents $m$ and $n$ are with n described as a cubic, but I want to understand the influence of each factor on the carbon intensity. The only variables that change each hour in this equation are $v_i, S_i, D_i$. I have a panel dataset of ships (hourly, per voyage and ship). Aside from plotting each explanatory variable against $C_i$ and looking at r-squared, can this equation be transformed using a log-log specification and then perform statistical regression?

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes. Various software packages offer you the option for bespoke non-linear models e.g. in SAS you have PROC NLMIXED (frequentist estimation) or in R you have things like [`brms` (Bayesian models)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brms/vignettes/brms_nonlinear.html) (there's also `nlme`). Key considerations would be parameterization (e.g. do you put some quantities that can only ever be positive on a log-scale and then put exp(quantity) in where needed?), numerical stability (some things might be more stable on a log-scale or with certain in-built stable functions) and whether there should be random effects (and on what - e.g. is there a random ship effect on the intercept or perhaps do other parameters vary between ships?).

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, this is not a typical stats estimation as I do not observe C (dependent variable) from real data. It is a mathematical function to estimate C. In the real world, we would observe the numerator (fuel consumption) and denominator (distance times size) which make up C and could then perform stats regression with fixed effects. The motivation here is only to decompose the equation to understand the contribution of each factor.